# How to create a decorator that produces a new class property that is a mapping or transformation of the decorated property

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I'm trying to figure out how to write a decorator that consumes an already existing class property and generates a mapped or transformed version of that property that also updates every time the value of the original property updates.

For example, `@upperCase` would generate a new property (with the key `` `${DECORATED_PROPERTY}_UPPERCASE` ``) that converts the string to upper case, and `@double` would generate a new property (with the key `` `${DECORATED_PROPERTY}_DOUBLE` ``) that doubles the value of every number in an array.

```
class MyClass {
  @upperCase word = 'hamburger';
  @double numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
}

const foo = new MyClass();
console.log(foo.word_UPPERCASE); // 'HAMBURGER'
console.log(foo.numbers_DOUBLE); // [2, 4, 6, 8]

foo.word = 'new word';
// See the derived property update in accordance with the original when the original changes value
foo.word_UPPERCASE = 'NEW WORD';
```

I've played around with `Object.defineProperty` and the `get` and `set` properties on it, but nothing seems to work.  For example, when I try this implementation for `@upperCase`:

```
export function upperCase(target:any, propertyKey:string) {
  let value:string = target[propertyKey];

  const getter = function () {
    return value.toUpperCase();      // Error below gets thrown at this line
  }

  const setter = function (newVal:string) {
    value = newVal;
  }

  Object.defineProperty(target, `${propertyKey}_UPPERCASE`, {
    get: getter,
    set: setter,
  })
}
```

and use it in the class like `@upperCase word:string = 'foobar';`, if I then `console.log(this['word_UPPERCASE'])`, I get the following error:

`TypeError: can't access property "toUpperCase", value is undefined` thrown at the line commented above where the `getter` is trying to return `value.toUpperCase()`.

Comment: The getter should `return this[propertyKey].toUpperCase();`. It's not obvious what the setter should do since you can't un-uppercase something.

Comment: Thank you! That did it. I agree about the setter, I was just adapting another example I'd found and thought it was required for `defineProperty`, but all I needed was the getter.

Comment: A property with only a `get` accessor is highly useful and allows for the creation of truly immutable objects. You probably want to add `enumerable: true` to your descriptor. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/object/defineproperty) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Aluan Haddad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915893/aluan-haddad), the answer is simply:

```
function upperCase(target:any, propertyKey:string) {

  Object.defineProperty(target, `${propertyKey}_UPPERCASE`, {
    get: function () {
      return this[propertyKey].toUpperCase();
    },
    enumerable: true,
  })

}
```

To use:

```
class MyClass {
  @upperCase word:string = 'hello';
  word_UPPERCASE!:string;

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.word);
    console.log(this.word_UPPERCASE);
  }
}

// Output:
// hello 
// HELLO
```